What's the difference between all of the ways to supply an Executor to a CompletableFuture (and composed methods)?
I'm using Java's CompletableFutures for a project, and I got a bit confused on how there are multiple ways to pass an Executor to a CompletableFuture to pass control off to a different thread. Consider an example where there is the main thread, then thread-1 and thread-2 from the created thread pool.
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("hello world");

future
    .thenCompose(result -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hi again"));

future
    .thenCompose(result -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hi again!", executor));

future
    .thenComposeAsync(result -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hi again!"), executor);

future
    .thenComposeAsync(result -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hi again!", executor), executor);

Basically, how is each part of the composed future is executed, and on what threads?
I tried running the following sample code that logs the thread name to stdout
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("hello world");

        // Case 0: Print the thread at the beginning of main()
        System.out.println("Case 0: main executed on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        // Case 1: No executor specified for inner supplyAsync
        future.thenCompose(result -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Case 1 (lambda): executed on thread: " + threadName);
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                String innerThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Case 1 (supplyAsync): hi again executed on thread: " + innerThreadName);
                return "hi again";
            });
        }).join();

        // Case 2: Executor specified for inner supplyAsync
        future.thenCompose(result -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Case 2 (lambda): executed on thread: " + threadName);
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                String innerThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Case 2 (supplyAsync): hi again! executed on thread: " + innerThreadName);
                return "hi again!";
            }, executor);
        }).join();

        // Case 3: Executor specified for thenComposeAsync, but not for inner supplyAsync
        future.thenComposeAsync(result -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Case 3 (lambda): executed on thread: " + threadName);
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                String innerThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Case 3 (supplyAsync): hi again! executed on thread: " + innerThreadName);
                return "hi again!";
            });
        }, executor).join();

        // Case 4: Executor specified for both thenComposeAsync and inner supplyAsync
        future.thenComposeAsync(result -> {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Case 4 (lambda): executed on thread: " + threadName);
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                String innerThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Case 4 (supplyAsync): hi again! executed on thread: " + innerThreadName);
                return "hi again!";
            }, executor);
        }, executor).join();

        // Shutdown the executor
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

which resulted in the following output
Case 0: main executed on thread: main
Case 1 (lambda): executed on thread: main
Case 1 (supplyAsync): hi again executed on thread: Thread-0
Case 2 (lambda): executed on thread: main
Case 2 (supplyAsync): hi again! executed on thread: pool-1-thread-1
Case 3 (lambda): executed on thread: pool-1-thread-2
Case 3 (supplyAsync): hi again! executed on thread: Thread-1
Case 4 (lambda): executed on thread: pool-1-thread-1
Case 4 (supplyAsync): hi again! executed on thread: pool-1-thread-1

The results aren't readily explainable to me.
This was run on the Programiz online compiler, so not sure what their JVM options are in terms of thread naming.

Simply if you specify an executor then it runs on the executor thread-pool otherwise it will run on the common fork-join pool

There is no point in wrapping a supplyAsync in a thenCompose[Async] at all. Just use thenApplyAsync(result -> "hi again!", executor)

runAsync, supplyAsync, and composeAsync mean “do this is another thread.”  Either CompletableFuture uses the default ForkJoinPool to do it in another thread, or CompletableFuture uses an Executor that you specify to do it in another thread.  (Of course, depending on the type of Executor used, the asynchronous operation might not actually happen in another thread.)
